# Homework at Hogwarts

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

Probably a moot point, but if you're writing an essay at Hogwarts, do you have to cite your sources or is plagiarism not a thing? Just a thought that struck me as I started reading the first chapter of PoA

Comment: Hermione certainly let Harry and Ron copy her homework on many occasions as well as lending them her History of Magic notes (which doubtless formed the basis of their work in that subject). I'm sure that Hogwarts teachers would ask questions if too much of an essay looked plagiarised, much as a normal Muggle teacher would. They wouldn't ordinarily check for it though. Only in the official exams are anti-cheating spells used on the parchment, quills etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are [extensive examples](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Homework) of various Potterverse characters being assigned essays as part of their normal homework as well as as punishment for various transgressions;

As far as I'm aware, we never see the *end result* of these essay assignments so from an in-universe perspective it's impossible to tell whether students are expected to provide footnotes.

We certainly see students removing books from the library to assist them in their studies and as Hogwart's education principles seems to follow the model of a UK boarding school, it's unlikely that students can simply write whatever they like without adding some kind of justification.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Some men just want to watch the world burn... :-)

Comment: @Richard - Amen. An upvote to counter a good answer. Also, you may add that they are frequently studying in the library, even non-Hermione lazy ones - if they didn't need references, the textbooks would be enough.

Comment: FYI - some Potterverse browsing may uncover examples of essays.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine if you're taking a quote directly out of a previously written source, then yes its to be cited. However the wizarding world does it a little differently.

They don't for example do "Hermione is using Harry for her own ends" (Rita Skeeter, Daily Prophet"

But they might for example say:

"According to Rita Skeeter who works for the Daily Prophet, Hermione is using Harry Potter for her own ends."

Comment: Do you have any canon backup for this answer?

Comment: I'd have to go back and re-read directly out of the books, but I never recall seeing citations inside of parenthisis like a standard 'muggle' essay while reading snippets of the daily prophet articles in the HP books. This site shows all the articles of the phrophet and as you can see they have their own way of citing sources. http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Daily_Prophet_articles

Comment: This is hardly limited to the wizarding world. In much academic writing in-prose references are preferred for legibility.